# Override the neutral language of a specific resource file within an assembly

Tags: .net, localization, assemblies, resources

I have an assembly that contains several resource files. Most of them have the neutral language 'nl' (Dutch, specified on the assembly as the neutral language), so I don't specify the 'nl' in their filenames.

However, I'm putting strings in the English language in some other resource files (they are internal error messages) and I will never provide Dutch translations of them.

If I name those resource files something like 'Errors.en.resx', no designer class is generated (breaks the build) because there is no 'Errors.resx'. This is annoying because now I have to put 'en' strings into a 'nl'-implied resource file and I really don't want to translate those strings to 'nl' or provide empty strings just to satisfy the compiler.

Is there a way to override the neutral language on a specific resource file or perhaps somehow have the 'Errors.en.resx' build a designer class?

Comment: If they are not to be translated, why not use constants in a static class?

Comment: Good point, I'll consider that although I'll lose the comfort of the resource editor in VS.

Comment: I have no answers for you, but your English is better than some of my friends is.  Here's a cookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the strings are not to be translated, consider the use of constants in a static class if they are not referenced by other assemblies.

If the strings are reused across several assemblies consider specifying them as `static readonly` since this will allow for the other assemblies to load a new version of the strings without the need to rebuild them. For this scenario you can even go one step further and specify a public static property with only the `get` accessor which in turns uses the `private static readonly` field.